# check whether data present in row of database with product key

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with code. It works if data in row of Database is present. But if data is not present then also it gives message as 12345-12345-12345-12345(sample key) already registered . use another key.

This is code:

```
   $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT pkey FROM license_key WHERE pkey ='$userEnteredProductKey'");
      if(is_resource($namecheck) && mysql_num_rows($namecheck) > 0 ){
            $sql_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($namecheck);
            echo $userEnteredProductKey . " already registered . use another key";
   }
```

Please correct me if i go wrong.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Maybe you need to check both whether the key is valid and whether it has been used. Is there a field for that in the license_key table or a table for that?

Comment: yes there is field in table.

Comment: Then you need to ask the database something like: SELECT pkey FROM license_key WHERE pkey ='$userEnteredProductKey' AND used = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all before doing anything else please phase out **mysql_*** functions and switch to use **PDO** or **MySQLi**. Especially if your project is dealing with serial keys or some unique keys. As of now your query can be easily hacked by **injecting** extra **SQL**

Back to problem:

since it executes **echo** statement it means that if statement gets executed which means **is_resource**() and **mysql_num_rows**() both return true.

why dont you check the database and see again if there exists a record with **12345-12345-12345-12345**, seems like **mysql_num_rows** returns **> 0**

Also why dont you var_dump **$sql_result** and see what it prints

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using MySQLi now, but still same happening with it.
Here is my code:
`$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT custname FROM license_key WHERE pkey = '$userEnteredProductKey'");
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $row['custname'];
  echo ("used registed key");
}`

Can anyone tell where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to use mysql_query.  Try this below.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_SELECT, DB_PORT);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT pkey FROM license_key WHERE pkey =?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$userEnteredProductKey) ;

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result( $pKey );
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if($pkey!=''){
  echo $userEnteredProductKey . " already registered . use another key";
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answer. But it is not working. It replace the row.